# Terraform to have a for_each and dynamic block in the same resource? Or can I have multiple for_each in a resource statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Can I have a for_each and dynamic block in the same resource statement ?
Or can I have multiple for_each in a resource statement
/// Creating 2 EC2 instances ///

```
resource "aws_instance" "ABC" {
  count = 2
  ami           = var.AMIX
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  subnet_id = xxx
  vpc_security_group_ids = [data.aws_security_group.SG.id]
  key_name = var.AMIX-KEY
  tags = {
    Name = abc)
  }
}
```

/// Creating local dict with subnet name and subnet id /// This has 2 subnets for ec2 instance 1 and 2 subnets for ec2 instance 2

```
locals {
# With List 
  subnets = flatten([
    for subnet_details in aws_subnet.SUBNET : {
      subnet_name = subnet_details.tags.Name,
      subnet_id = subnet_details.id
      } if contains(["abc", "xyz"], subnet_details.tags.Name)
  ])
}
```

/// Local subnets output.

```
 dev = [
      + {
          + subnet_id    = "A"
          + subnet_name  = "DEV1"
        },
      + {
          + subnet_id    = "B"
          + subnet_name  = "DEV1"
        },
      + {
          + subnet_id    = "C"
          + subnet_name  = "DEV2"
        },
      + {
          + subnet_id    = "D"
          + subnet_name  = "DEV2"
        },
    ]
```

**/// How to attach EC2 instances with Network Interfaces  ???
Loop two times in attachment as I need to tie two ec2 instances depending on the subnet_name 2 subnets get ec2-1 and 2 subnets get ec2-2 and based on that they will get the device_index ///**

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "NICS" {
  for_each = {
    for subnet_id, subnet_name in local.subnets : subnet_id => subnet_name
  }
  subnet_id = each.value.subnet_id
  security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.SG.id]
  tags = {
    Name = each.value.subnet_name
  }
  attachment {
  instance = ?
  device_index = 1
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? An interface can be attached to only one instance at a time. So you can't have a `aws_network_interface` with multiple `attachment`, as it would indicate that you are attaching a single interface to multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: I am using a medium t3 instance. You can attach multiple network interfaces to it right?
As such the end goal is that these ec2 instances are FW instances with PAN (Palo Alto), but using EC2 instances for testing

Comment: A single instance can have multiple NICs, but a single NIC can be only in one instance. Thus its not clear what do you want to achieve. What do you want to accomplish by " Loop two times in attachment "?

Comment: Can you provide example of your `local.subnets`? Its difficult to see what is it its form, how many you have elements there without any actual example what `local.subnets` looks like.

Comment: Ahh I see. What I am trying to do is there are 4 subnets in local.subnet (due to my condition there). I am creating interfaces with for_each, so 4 interfaces are created in aws_network_interface, but for every interface, a specific ec2 instance needs to be added . So I think should somehow try to add that ec2 instance id in the local.subnet dict ? subnet with tags "A" (there are two of them) "A" will get ec2 instance aws_instance.ABC.tags.Name == "Y" and subnets with tags "B" (there are 2 of them) will get instance "Z" ? But how do I iterate over the device index

Comment: I mean, actual example. What does `local.subnets` look like. You can update your question to provide the example. So far you have only your `flatten` definition, but there is no example of what is the outcome of your expression.

Comment: I added that to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following version of your code. I haven't run the code, but but you can consider the idea behind it:

```
variable "instance_name" {
  default = ["Y", "Z"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "ABC" {

  for_each = var.instance_name

  ami           = var.AMIX
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  subnet_id = xxx
  vpc_security_group_ids = [data.aws_security_group.SG.id]
  key_name = var.AMIX-KEY

  tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
}
```

Then, you would create four NICs based on `local.subnets` when you
also specify instance name. Also I would separate creation of NICs from their attachments using [aws_network_interface_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_attachment):

```
locals {

  subnets = [
       {
           subnet_id    = "A"
           subnet_name  = "DEV1"
           instance_name = "Y"
        },
       {
           subnet_id    = "B"
           subnet_name  = "DEV1"
           instance_name = "Y"           
        },
       {
           subnet_id    = "C"
           subnet_name  = "DEV2"
           instance_name = "Z"                      
        },
       {
           subnet_id    = "D"
           subnet_name  = "DEV2"
           instance_name = "Z"                                 
        }
    ]
}


resource "aws_network_interface" "NICS" {
  
  for_each = {for subnet in local.subnets : (subnet.subnet_name) => subnet}

  subnet_id       = each.value.subnet_id
  security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.SG.id]

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.subnet_name
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "test" {

  for_each = {for subnet in local.subnets : (subnet.subnet_name) => subnet}

  instance_id          = aws_instance.ABC[each.value.instance_name].id
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.NICS[each.key].id
  device_index         = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not think of using interface attachment 
Also, device index is a counter for interfaces.
And currently, my subnets do not have instance name. If I were to have two for loops, I'll have 8 key value pairs. As my condition is for the subnet name and not instance name and I cannot have if [Y, Z] in subnet name or [A] in instance name